# A/B Testing AKA Split Testing

Tags: c#, javascript, anti-bot

I am making an application to register accounts on a webpage. That webpage contains a field that's called ab_test_data, The content of a field will be generated when I click "Sign up" button, It's generated by a javascript function that does a sort of a complicated algorithm which I totally don't understand. I want to be able to understand what is A/B testing and how it's used as an Anti-bot technology. I would also want to understand how to bypass it if possible.

note: The questions assumes that I will be using HttpWebRequest/Response to send my data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you're asking us to help you spam?

Comment: Not exactly, I am trying to automate a task.

Comment: You have to reverse enginneer that javascript. I don't think you can get a general answer here. Reverse engineering and bypassing a security measure on a website can't be legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A/B Testing is not specifically an anti-bot technology. 
However this may be the side-effect if the site is requiring that it contains the results of the A/B test.

A/B Testing is a way to test what impact specific changes have on your user's behaviour. For example, changing the way you lay out a product page and whether this improves sales.

Wikipedia has more information on [A/B Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing)

I would suggest altering the site behaviour so that you don't require the A/B Test data (or setting it to a known value) if you wish to automate your process.